# Bash script to append A records from user input and reload bind?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

What would be a script that appends A records to DNS via user input?

This is how I imagined its workflow:

Script asks user for name.

Stores the provided name in a variable.

(line break)Script asks user for IP address.

Stores the provided IP in a variable.

Script appends NAME IN A IP(properly formatted) at the end of the /path/to/zone/file.

sudo service bind9 reload

exit

Comment: Use nsupdate instead

Comment: I tried but when I hit send I get ; TSIG error with server: tsig indicates error
update failed: NOTAUTH(BADKEY)
 even though I copy pasted the key from rndc.key.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate